How to import .db file to pgAdmin 4?
I want to import a file with .db extension into pgAdmin 4, how can I do that? It is not a .tar file but a .db file. Is there any way to import this database?
Thanks in advance for the help.

Nobody can tell you that unless you can tell us what format the file is in. The extension doesn't mean anything in particular. If you are on a linux/unix based system try running the file command on the filename. If it is text/sql then you will want to use psql, otherwise it might be a pg_restore compatible dump, or something else completely

I am a mac user and this is what I got when i tried to find the filetype : 'sqlite-sakila.db: SQLite 3.x database, last written using SQLite version 3034001, file counter 46364, database pages 1423, cookie 0x4b, schema 4, UTF-8, version-valid-for 46364'

It's not a postgresql dump at all. That is an sqlite database. You can open it with that and export the raw SQL. You will then probably need to do some cleanup on that before you can load it to a PostgreSQL database.

Here is how you can import a PostgreSQL database in PGAdmin 4.

Right Click on database(which you want to export).



Click on the browse file button



Select destination & Give file name



Click Save, then click on Backup.

This will save your file in SQL format, which you can use later to export the database.
As far as I know, it is impossible(till now) to get an import file with .db extension but, Using this method you can get a backup file of your database with .sql extension.
Also, you can use the pgdump command to get a database backup.
